# Why is this contradiction using axiom of constructibility incorrect?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

Today I thought of this paradox and I'm trying to find the wrong assumption that causes it. Does anyone know what is wrong in the following argument:

let $$A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|\exists\phi:\forall a\neq x: \phi(x)=true \wedge \phi(a)=false\}$$ where $\phi$ is a formula with one free variable

Gödel proved that there exist a specific well-ordering on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in ZFC and showed under the axiom of constructibility that this subset is $\mathbb{R}$. Denote that ordering "$\leq$"

Now consider the set $\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus A$. It has a unique least element $e$ under "$\leq$" which satisfies $$\phi(x):=(x\in\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus A) \wedge (\forall y \in \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus A:x \leq y)$$ so $e\in A$ which is a contradiction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this: http://karagila.org/2015/name-that-number/

Comment: Also, a word of advice. When you think that you found a contradiction to a well-established axiom of mathematics, studied by many people who were and are very smart... maybe it's better to say "I think that I'm missing something here" rather than "Is this contradiction correct?" Always assume the blame is on you, even when you're sure that it's not. Humility is a virtue for mathematicians.

Comment: Thanks for your word of advise but I couldn't find any sources saying that this axiom is consistent with ZFC, and posing the question the way you propose is basically assuming that it is. That is why I posed the questing like that. I edited it, but could you give me sources on it's consistency?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility is a start.

Comment: Are you implying that I am to lazy to find the answer myself? I have of course read the wikipedia page on it before I turned to stack exchange.  This page contains almost no information, 1 external link and 1 refrence to which I have no acces. Also, this page does not say a word about it's consistency

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe is probably better. I'm not implying that you're lazy. I don't know what you did or didn't do, but your question doesn't seem lazy. So no, I'm not implying that.

Comment: You just defined $A = \mathbb R$.  Witness $\phi(z) = (z = x)$.  Ignore everyone talking about limitations of first order logic and so forth, that is irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielV Presumably the $\varphi$ involved in the definition of $A$ are **parameter-free** so that doesn't trivialize. Once you note that, then the technical details about first-order logic are *absolutely* relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple steps in your argument that are broken. (For simplicity, let's just assume at the outset that we're working in a model of $ZFC+V=L$.)

- The set $A$ is defined by quantifying over **formulas**. This can't be done in first-order logic. So, we can't talk about $A$ directly, necessarily. In particular, the formula "$x$ is the $\le$-least element of $\mathbb{R}-A$" isn't a first-order formula, and so can't be used to show that $x$ is in $A$. This is related in spirit to the Berry paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox). You have to be careful when talking about definability!
- A more minor objection: You assume that $\mathbb{R}-A$ is nonempty. How do you know this? In fact, this is not necessarily true - see http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597.

Comment: Thanks, I should learn more about what first order and all that means... On your second point: I didn't state this, but wouldn't that imply that the reals are countable? if every real can be described by a formula, which can be written as a string, couldn't you make an injection into N?

Comment: @JensRenders Yes! But that's not a contradiction . . .  unless the bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ exists *inside the model*. As a consequence of the **Lowenheim-Skolem theorem**, there are models of ZFC which are countable (this is sometimes separately called "Skolem's paradox"). The point is that, if $M$ is a countable model of ZFC, the bijection between $\mathbb{R}^M$ and $\mathbb{N}^M$ does not exist *inside the model*.  This is an important point about definability and first-order logic. Pointwise definable models of set theory are extreme cases of this phenomenon.

Comment: Taken in isolation, the definition of $A$ is perfectly legitimate within first-order set theory.  As Asaf's answer suggests, the problem seems rather to be that the question equivocates between two notions of "formula", "definition", etc.

Comment: @mmw This is not true - the definition of $A$ is implicitly quantifying over first-order formulas in the language of set theory (yes, there's potential ambiguity here, but from the rest of the argument it's clear this is what the OP means). And this isn't something you can do in first-order logic.

Comment: My understanding is that first order set theory is perfectly adequate to develop a theory of syntax and then to define truth-in-a-structure.  Surely you don't disagree with that.

Comment: @mmw "Surely" I don't? :D "Perfectly adequate" is such a dangerous phrase. First-order logic is **not** capable of defining internal truth predicates. Although we *can* define restricted versions of $A$ - say, the set of reals definable in the field of real numbers $\{r: \exists \varphi\forall s\in\mathbb{R}([(\mathbb{R}; +, \times)\models\varphi(s)]\iff s=r)\}$ - the OP's set $A$ is looking at formulas *evaluated in $V$ itself*: $A=\{r: \exists \varphi\forall s\in\mathbb{R}([V\models\varphi(s)]\iff s=r)\}$. (cont'd)

Comment: And this is something we cannot do. Google "Tarski's undefinability theorem" if you don't believe me, or just try to explicitly write down a first-order definition of $A$. (Note: Tarski's theorem doesn't immediately prove $A$ is undefinable - sometimes $A$ is definable, e.g. if $V=L$ - but it does show that the obvious approach to defining $A$ doesn't work.) The claim "the definition of $A$ is perfectly legitimate within first-order set theory" is simply wrong.

Comment: What I said is that first-order logic adequately formalizes the notion of truth-in-a-structure.  But in first-order formalization of model theory, "structure" typically refers to a set.

Comment: As for the claim that what the OP "really meant" is $\phi^V$ rather than $\langle \mathbb R,\cdots\rangle\models\ulcorner\phi\urcorner$... that's what I was carping about in the first place.  What the OP wrote is $\phi(x)=true$, which suggests unclarity about the distinction.  It would seem peculiar for someone reasonably competent in first-order logic (like the OP, pretty clearly) to think that $\exists \phi\cdots$ is a formula in the language of ZF, unless $\phi$ were ranging over codes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misunderstanding of what does it mean for a real number to be definable.

There are one of two possible mistakes here:

1. $\phi$ is a formula in the language of set theory. But then you can't quantify over it, because $\phi$ is not an object of the universe of set theory, it is an object of the meta-theory.
2. $\phi$ is limited to some structure defined using $\Bbb R$ (first, second, whatever order field axioms with some additional functions or operators as you'd like).

   In that case, either you end up being able to define *every* real number, or you found a real number which is not definable *in this given structure*, which gives it a definition *outside* the structure. Namely, you've shown that the first real number which is not definable in this structure, is in fact definable in the full universe of sets.

   This is not a contradiction to anything. Just like no element of $\Bbb Q$ is definable as a linearly ordered set, but of course that you can do some sort of parameter free definition of $\Bbb Q$ which gives you some canonical enumeration and therefore you can pick the least rational in that enumeration. This is not a definition over a linearly ordered set anymore.

It should also be pointed out that despite this being a misunderstanding, there are in fact models where *every* real number is definable (in the global sense of the word, namely you are allowed to use the entire set theoretic universe for the definition).

Answer (score 0):

**You say:** Let $$A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}|\exists\phi:\forall a\neq x: \phi(x)=true \wedge \phi(a)=false\}$$ where $\phi$ is a formula with one free variable.

**Consider this:** For each $x$ you can always choose $\phi(y)$ to be the simple formula $y = x$.  Then $\phi(x)$ is $x = x$, which is $true$, while for $a \neq x$, $\phi(a)$ is $a = x$, which is $false$.

This implies $A = \mathbb{R}$.  So your final argument cannot be carried out, because the difference set is actually empty.